# reference to generic type in XML code comment

Tags: c#, xml, documentation, reference, generics

As I know, in a XML comment for a C# type/method, it is possible to reference a generic type in a  tag like so:

```
///<see cref="name.space.typename&lt;T&rt;(paramtype)">
```

But I think, there was another syntax, which is less clumsy? Something, to get rid of those html entities '<'? I cannot find it right now. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Here's a citation of a no longer available, good article on documentation:

> The compiler team decided to improve
> this by allowing an alternate syntax
> to refer to generic types and methods
> in doc comments.  Specifically,
> instead of using the open and close
> angle-brackets it’s legal to use the
> open and close curly braces.  The
> example above would then become:

```
class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// DoSomething takes a <see cref="List{T}"/>
    /// </summary>
    void DoSomething(List<int> al) { }
}
```

So, in your case:

```
///<see cref="name.space.typename{T}(paramtype)"/>
```

Here are a couple of newer references from Microsoft:

- [XML Documentation Comments (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/xml-documentation-comments)
- [Documenting your code with XML comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc)

Comment: Yes, but the curly braces do show up in Visual Studio (2005..2012) Intellisense as `{T}`, not as `<T>`.

Comment: @PierreArnaud - FWIW, the new Roslyn-based language analysis in Visual Studio 2015 now correctly displays the reference to List<T> as 'List<T>' instead of 'List{T}' in the tooltip :)

Answer (score 9):

Use curly brackets:

```
///<see cref="name.space.typename{T}(paramtype)">
```